# Gradually fade buttons only if they aren't currently being hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have forward and backward buttons for an image gallery. Currently, they fade away when the mouse is idle. Any movement on the page will show them again. Here's the code:

```
//fade out previous/next buttons on mouse idle
var timer;
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    $('.fader').fadeIn();
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.fader').fadeOut(1500)
    }, 1000)
})
```

This works fine, but I also would like the buttons to not fade out at all if they are currently being hovered.

As a test, I've tried this code:

```
//both buttons are stored in class .fader

//when buttons are hovered over
$(".fader").hover(
    function(){
        //give them this class
        $(this).toggleClass('is-hover');
    })

//if buttons have .is-hover class, print test statement to console
if($(".fader").hasClass('is-hover')){
    console.log("true");
}
```

I'm hoping to see the test "true" statement printed to the console, but it's not happening.

Ultimately, I'd like to wrap the first function in the second. *If buttons are not being hovered over, then perform this timed fadeout of buttons.*

---

Here is where the buttons are in the HTML:

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div ng-show="show" class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!--The buttons-->

    <div class="swiper-button-next fader"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev fader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include your html code please?

Comment: Sure, one moment.

Comment: Okay, I've add the HTML.

Comment: I know you are trying to find an answer in jquery but I am curious why you don't want to use css for this, especially if it is just a hover fade-in/out?

Comment: Actually, your buttons are not within a `div` that fades.

Comment: The buttons are fading just fine, and the first jQuery function does the job, so I figured I could do the hovering in jQuery as well, but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: If CSS is a more elegant solution to this, then I'd be interested in trying that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS for the button hovering...
But to track mouse movement on the document, a script is needed.
You can use both! ;)

```js
// To track mouse movement and fadein all buttons
var timer;

$(document).on("mousemove",function(){
  $(".fader").addClass("faderShowOnMouseMove");
  if(typeof(timer)!="undefined"){
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $(".fader").removeClass("faderShowOnMouseMove");
  },1000);
});
```

```css
/* Base style for buttons */
.fader {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

/* For single button hovering */
.fader:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Used with JS mouse movement */
.faderShowOnMouseMove{
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Just for this demo ;) */
.swiper-pagination{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Swiper -->
<div ng-show="show" class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    Hover over here! <i>(right below this text)</i><br>
    <div class="swiper-pagination">
      
      <!--The buttons-->
      <button class="fader">1</button>
      <button class="fader">2</button>
      <button class="fader">3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The buttons have a class of fader.

Comment: Whatever element having `.fader` class will behave like this it the parent is visible. I edited.

Comment: I think the big reason I wanted to use javascript was to track _any_ mouse movement, and any time the mouse moves, the forward and back buttons should reappear. That's why I went with Javascript

Comment: If I could somehow track mousemove in CSS, this could work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear about that in the question. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I did try this code, and it's simple. I think I even started building this in CSS and then switched to Javascript because of the mouse move situation.